How do I specify that different Huggingface Trainers in the same process use different GPUs?
I have instantiated multiple Huggingface Trainers in the same process and each of them train different models. Now I need to count the GPU cost of each Trainer, so I need to make different Trainers exclusive to one GPU for training to get accurate statistics.
I have tried to set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES as
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"

but this would cause all Trainers to use GPU1.

There are several options. Add a device parameter to your launch script or use different processes for example.
